# How can I do toLeftOf for two Id's in same XML layout in Android?

Tags: android

In this below XML. there are Imageview and Progressbar are in same position. means if one is visible then other is Gone.

So, initially imageview is visible bydefault and p.bar visibility is gone. So when user click on delete button, delete visibility will be gone and p.bar will be visible. Now the problem is text is not overlapping for imageview because I did   `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/delete"` in linear layout, but when p.bar is visible that time text are overlapping. How can I fix that?

Problem Image:
[image]

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/delete"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventDes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventAttendee"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventStart"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventEnd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventLocation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:tint="@color/colorBlack"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete_24" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**What I tried:**

I tried to wrap ImageView and Progressbar into new relative/linear layout and that layout id, I used for toLeftOf, but it's not working

Comment: I think i know how to fix that. What you are doing with the delete icon after clicking that? gone?

Comment: yupp, delete  icon gone and p.bar  visibility visible. For delete, text are not overlapping, but when p.bar is visible that time left side texts are overlapping

Comment: Make it `invisible` instead of `gone`.

Comment: but both are in same pos. it won't take that pos, if I'lll do invisible

Comment: and also I want to know for learning purpose also that how it can be fixed without any hack?

Comment: For learning purposes use `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Arey baba, that will do later, now at least give solution no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linear_layout_2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventDes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventAttendee"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventStart"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventEnd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventLocation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:tint="@color/colorBlack"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete_24" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

       </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: let me chk this

Comment: Hey in question, I already mention no, that I tried with linear and relative layout but it's not working

Comment: whole view is changing

Comment: @ShefaliSingh The whole view is changing? Mind sharing the image?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14DqlsHlPTbqDHhHuSROnPJo7zvmK1Y_t

Comment: Lol, I'm laughing :P

Comment: Plzzzzzzzz, Do you know 1 crore doubts are there in my mind, and no one has to solve. And I'm googling everytime, but some doubts I'm not able to solve

Comment: Can you please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62144628/why-doesnt-html-fromhtml-not-working-for-string-in-android