# How to get size for Firestore POSTID Collection in Android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

See the code:

```
private void initFirebase() {
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
                mDatabase.collection(POST_ID).document("1").collection(PREVIEW)
                        .get()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                        postMap.putAll(document.getData());
                                    }
                                    if (postMap != null) {
                                        Post post = new Post();
                                        post.setTitle(Objects.requireNonNull(postMap.get(POST_NAME)).toString());
                                        post.setDesc(Objects.requireNonNull(postMap.get(POST_DESC)).toString());
                                        post.setUrl(Objects.requireNonNull(postMap.get(POST_URL)).toString());
                                        postList.add(post);
                                    }

                                    setAdapter();
                                } else {
                                    showLog("Error getting documents: " + task.getException());
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

instead of  `for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) {`   **16** I want the size which existed in my Firestore Collection. I tried all suggestion, but there is no `mDatabase.collection(POST_ID).size()`

DB Structure:

```
Firestore-root
     |
     --- PostId (collecton)
          |
          ---
```

**I want the size of postId collection.**

Comment: Why are you looping? You never used the variable `i` in the code.

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun I'll loop 'i' here:  mDatabase.collection(POST_ID).document("1")

Comment: You mean `mDatabase.collection(POST_ID).document(i)` ??

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun correct

Comment: You wanna do that because you need all the documents in the database?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun yupp

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun See my DB structure is different. I manually created that in console. so better you don't think that much. Just tell me how will I get the size?

Comment: Umm? Check answer.

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun That won't help, because after I , I have some more children/collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For size

```
int count = 0;
db.collection("POST_ID")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
               count = task.getResult().size();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });

private void initFirebase() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                mDatabase.collection(POST_ID).document(i).collection(PREVIEW)
                        .get()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                        postMap.putAll(document.getData());
                                    }
                                    if (postMap != null) {
                                        Post post = new Post();
                                        post.setTitle(Objects.requireNonNull(postMap.get(POST_NAME)).toString());
                                        post.setDesc(Objects.requireNonNull(postMap.get(POST_DESC)).toString());
                                        post.setUrl(Objects.requireNonNull(postMap.get(POST_URL)).toString());
                                        postList.add(post);
                                    }

                                    setAdapter();
                                } else {
                                    showLog("Error getting documents: " + task.getException());
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Then use this `count` variable as size.

Comment: Arey yar, after   mDatabase.collection(POST_ID).document("1"). this I have /preview/some other fields for every id

Comment: please tell me about size

Comment: @ShefaliSingh check update.

Comment: Arey baba, why you're not understanding, see: postId / here i / preview /....

Comment: that's why I want to loop

Comment: @ShefaliSingh what about now?

Comment: let me chk, I think it'll work, but why there is no size(), why we have to loop around n all?

Comment: Working, but bit lengthy process. Anyways Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you help me this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61857048/how-can-i-do-toleftof-for-two-ids-in-same-xml-layout-in-android

Comment: @ShefaliSingh no problem. You might wanna move the `count` variable inside your function.

Comment: yupp I'll do it