# Why doesn't Html.fromHtml not working for String in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase

[image]

One String value is coming from my firebase:

```java
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    //   binding.contentMain.noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()))
        postMap.putAll(document.getData());

    try {
        if (postMap != null)
            //binding.desc1.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(postMap.get(CONTENT)).toString());
            binding.desc1.setText(Html.fromHtml(Objects.requireNonNull(postMap.get(CONTENT)).toString()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now, I'll tell you what is coming inside String from Firestore, Actually I only manually written as a String field inside Firestore collection.:

```
This is the first text. \n\n This is a second text. \n This is the third text. \n\n Done. \n
```

Make sure that above line is just one String/firestore field.

In firestore, I stored the above value as a `String`, and fetching that value and showing it in Android. But it is not taking a new line. Instead, it is showing written \n along with other characters.

I tried with and without HTML. with \n and \r\n.

UPDATE: You can see below image how I stored in Firestore.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=19yry9top_W8LREw5SEaZKWYWSlnCP1io

Comment: This is happening because there is `\\n` instead of `\n`. You need to unescape it: `s.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\\\n");` or if you can just import apache commons then there is a static method `String op = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(s);`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat What exactly I need to write in Firesotore field?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48874269/6099347 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840608/how-do-i-add-a-newline-to-a-textview-in-android

Comment: @AniketSahrawat In my case, it isn't replacing with \n to \\n ; it I exactly coming what I written manually in collection field.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Check the edited question.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Check the image in question

Comment: @ShefaliSingh you want to show those lines in new lines?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun yes. I want to show lines as a next lines.

Answer (score 0):

In firestore you need to put two `\`s before `n` to add a new line.

if you are getting data from user or reading it from a file add this line before storing data:

```
str.replaceAll("\\n", "\n");
```

Comment: You are looking for word "unescape"

Comment: @AniketSahrawat tried via removing space as well. not working

Comment: it isn't replacing \\n with \n .  Don't know why!

Comment: Check the image in question

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=19yry9top_W8LREw5SEaZKWYWSlnCP1io

Answer (score 0):

use this method:

```java
  public Spanned getHtmlFormattedString(String value) {
        Spanned result = null;
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                result = Html.fromHtml(value, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT);
            } else {
                result = Html.fromHtml(value);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return result;
    }
```

in your case :

```java
binding.desc1.setText(getHtmlFormattedString(Objects.requireNonNull(postMap.get(CONTENT)).toString()));
```

### Update Answer

`\n` is not html tag , if you want to handle with `Html.fromHtml` you should replace `\n` with `<br/>` tag

so in your case :

```
binding.desc1.setText(getHtmlFormattedString(Objects.requireNonNull(postMap.get(CONTENT)).toString().replaceAll("\\n","<br/>")));
```

Comment: Check the image in question

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=19yry9top_W8LREw5SEaZKWYWSlnCP1io

Answer (score 0):

Your string is

```
This is the first text. \n\n This is a second text. \n This is the third text. \n\n Done. \n
```

This is quite weird.

**1)** Do you want `next line` after a full stop?

**2)** Can you edit or format the string at the time of saving?

If your case is `1` then what you can do is

Remove all the `/n` character and replace with `""`.

`String stringWithoutNewLine = yourString.replaceAll("\n","")`

Then it gonna look like this

```
This is the first text.  This is a second text.  This is the third text.  Done.
```

Now remove all the ".   " in the string and replace it with new line.

`String formattedString = yourString.replaceAll(".

",System.lineSeparator())`

You can chain these in one line and it will work because `replaceAll` returns a new `String`

Can you try this

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    //   binding.contentMain.noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document: Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()))
        postMap.putAll(document.getData());

    try {
        if (postMap != null)
            //binding.desc1.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(postMap.get(CONTENT)).toString());
            String string = postMap.get(CONTENT).toString();
            String finalString = string.replaceAll("\n","").replaceAll(".  ",System.lineSeparator())
            binding.desc1.setText(finalString)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Whatever I written in firestore, exactly that is coming. See question, what I written. Ans see image inside question what is coming.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=19yry9top_W8LREw5SEaZKWYWSlnCP1io

Comment: I have own project in Firebase. Whatever I want I can write in Firesotore DB manually. And I don't want new line after every full stop. It depends upon some articles. After paragraph I want/added new lines, so that, in android automatically space will come. And In question I gave just example.

Comment: @ShefaliSingh I would suggest you is to format the string before saving it to the firebase then you can successfully format the string. Otherwise, you are gonna have hard time formatting strings.